# Subprocess: Permission and No such file or directory error messages

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm using Python 3.7 with Idle on a Mac running OS 10.15.4 and am trying to learn the basics of subprocess, with little success despite much effort.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('/Applications/Safari.app')
```

This results in a lengthy error message ending with

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Applications/Safari.app'
```

Removing the first backslash and instead using

```
subprocess.Popen('Applications/Safari.app')
```

results in

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Applications/Safari.app': 'Applications/Safari.app'
```

When I replace Safari with TextEdit, which I'm more interested in using, I receive the second of these error messages regardless of whether I include a backslash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the full path to the executable:

```
subprocess.Popen('/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari')
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x1023414f0>
```

Alternatively there is the `webbrowser` module:

```
>>> import webbrowser
>>> s = webbrowser.get('safari')
>>> s.open('https://google.com')
```

Comment: @fishbacp: That's related to the application you are executing.

Comment: That was nice and simple. 

Is there an argument one can give subprocess to have the desired app open a particular file?

For example,

    subprocess.Popen('/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/Mathematica')

will open Mathematica, but I'd like to add an argument specifying a Mathematica notebook, e.g. "sample.nb" to be opened after Mathematica has started. 

For the app I ultimately plan to use (not Mathematica), the app has to be opened first. For some reason, one cannot right-click the particular file format and use "open-with" or associate the file type with the app.

Comment: Sorry for posting comment before finishing editing.

Comment: I dont know `Mathematica`, there might be command line arguments how to specify files to open. Or just `os.system('open /Volumes/Downloads/solars.xlsx')` which opens the given file in Excel for me.